# How do I stop converting underscores to \textsubscript while exporting from org to latex?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm using special blocks for equations or math containing underscores, for example

```
#+begin_equation 
\sum_{i=0}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
#+end_equation
```

However, when I see the corresponding tex file, I see that `_abc` has been converted to `\textsubscript{abc}`.

```
\begin{equation}
\(\sum\)\textsubscript{i=0}\textsuperscript{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
```

My expected export is:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
```

How do I tell emacs/org-mode to keep underscores as they are? For reference, Org mode version is 9.5.2.

PS: Exporting `\sum` without being surrounded by `\(...\)` seems to be another problem, but I might ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found it! [Org manual entry on Latex Fragments](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html) states that "Environments of any kind" are identified as latex fragments. "The only requirement is that the ‘\begin’ statement appears on a new line, preceded by only whitespace."

Thus, the org file can contain the below verbatim, and it will be exported correctly to the tex file. This appropriately leaves underscores and carets as they are.

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
```